# React useState - save variables to local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, use-effect, use-state

I'm new in React and state hooks.I'm trying to make a website about creating booklist and save it to local storage. Also uploading image to cloudinary. My problem is ; when i trying to save cloudinary image url to the localstorage, it saves previous url. I think i have a problem about useState hooks but i couldnt figure it. Below is my code.

LocalStorage.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import BookList from '../../components/BookList'
import CreateBook from '../../components/CreateBook'

const getLocalStorage = () => {
  let list = localStorage.getItem('liste')
  if (list) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('liste'))
  } else {
    return []
  }
}

const LocalStorage = () => {
  //state hooks
  const [list, setList] = useState(getLocalStorage)
  const [bookName, setBookName] = useState('')
  const [writerName, setWriterName] = useState('')
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState('')
  const [info, setInfo] = useState('')
  const [image, setImage] = useState('')
  const [uploadUrl, setUploadUrl] = useState('')
  let id


  //Function for submit button
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // conditions for fill the blanks
    if (!bookName || !writerName || !pageNumber || !image) {
      setInfo('Please fill the blanks')
    } else {
      try {
        const data = new FormData()
        data.append('file', image)
        data.append('upload_preset', 'book-list-project')
        data.append('cloud_name', 'book-list')
        let response = await fetch(
          'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/book-list/image/upload',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
          }
        )
        let result = await response.json()
        setUploadUrl(result.url)
        id = new Date().getTime().toString()
        const newBook = {
          id: id,
          bookName: bookName,
          writerName: writerName,
          pageNumber: pageNumber,
          uploadUrl: uploadUrl,
        }

        setList([...list, newBook])
        setBookName('')
        setWriterName('')
        setPageNumber('')
        setInfo('Book created')
        setImage('')
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
  }

  //Function for remove specific book from local storage
  const removeSpecificBook = (id) => {
    setList(list.filter((book) => book.id !== id))
  }

  // Function for clear all books from local storage
  const removeAllBooks = () => {
    setList([])
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('liste', JSON.stringify(list))
  }, [list])

  return (
    <div>
      <CreateBook
        bookName={bookName}
        writerName={writerName}
        pageNumber={pageNumber}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        info={info}
        setBookName={setBookName}
        setWriterName={setWriterName}
        setPageNumber={setPageNumber}
        setImage={setImage}
      />

      <BookList
        items={list}
        removeSpecificBook={removeSpecificBook}
        removeAllBooks={removeAllBooks}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default LocalStorage
```

Booklist.js

```
import React from 'react'

const BookList = ({ items, removeSpecificBook, removeAllBooks }) => {
  return (
    <div className='container mx-auto'>
      <div className='mt-20 flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center'>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div key={item.id} className='p-2 m-2 bg-yellow-100 w-1/4'>
              <div className='p-1 m-1 flex justify-center'>
                <img
                  className='object-contain h-52 w-52'
                  src={item.uploadUrl}
                  alt='some img'
                />
              </div>
              <div className='p-1 m-1'>
                <h5 className='font-semibold'>Book Name</h5>
                <h3>{item.bookName}</h3>
              </div>
              <div className='p-1 m-1'>
                <h5 className='font-semibold'>Writer Name</h5>
                <h3>{item.writerName}</h3>
              </div>
              <div className='p-1 m-1'>
                <h5 className='font-semibold'>Total Page</h5>
                <h3>{item.pageNumber}</h3>
              </div>
              <div className='flex justify-end'>
                <button
                  onClick={() => removeSpecificBook(item.id)}
                  className='px-4 py-2 bg-red-500 rounded-full text-white'
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
      {items.length > 1 && (
        <div className='flex justify-center my-5'>
          <button
            onClick={removeAllBooks}
            className='px-8 py-4 bg-red-500 rounded-full text-white'
          >
            Remove All
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default BookList
```

CreateBook.js

```
import React from 'react'

const CreateBook = ({
  bookName,
  writerName,
  pageNumber,
  handleSubmit,
  info,
  setBookName,
  setWriterName,
  setPageNumber,
  setImage,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <nav className='bg-blue-500  text-center text-white px-6 py-3'>
          Create Book
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div className='bg-red-200 mx-auto w-96 rounded-lg flex justify-center mt-20'>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
            <div className='p-3 text-center'>
              <h6>Enter Book Name</h6>
              <input
                value={bookName}
                onChange={(e) => setBookName(e.target.value)}
                className='rounded-md'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Book Name'
              />
            </div>
            <div className='p-3 text-center'>
              <h6>Enter Writer Name</h6>
              <input
                value={writerName}
                onChange={(e) => setWriterName(e.target.value)}
                className='rounded-md'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Writer Name'
              />
            </div>
            <div className='p-3 text-center'>
              <h6>Enter Total Page Number </h6>
              <input
                value={pageNumber}
                onChange={(e) => setPageNumber(e.target.value)}
                className='rounded-md'
                type='number'
                placeholder='Page Number'
              />
            </div>
            <div className='p-3 text-center'>
              <div>
                <h6>Upload Image</h6>
              </div>
              <div className='p-3'>
                <input
                  type='file'
                  onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className='flex justify-center p-3'>
              <button className='bg-blue-500 py-3 px-6 rounded-full text-white'>
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className='p-3 text-center  text-white'>
              <h3>{info}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateBook
```

Also please if you have any suggestions about my code structure, tell me. I dont have any programming history and trying to learn from beginning. I need every suggestions to go further learning programming. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setUploadUrl(result.url);
id = new Date().getTime().toString();
const newBook = {
  id: id,
  bookName: bookName,
  writerName: writerName,
  pageNumber: pageNumber,
  uploadUrl: uploadUrl
};
```

In here you are updating the uploadUrl to the newBook object. But the value of `uploadUrl` hold the previous record. Instead of setting from uploadUrl, set it from `result.url`.

Comment: Yes if i set it to result.url , problem is solving but when i setUploadUrl  to result.url , why is uploadUrl still be the previous result.url ? is there a way to make it current ? maybe useEffect ?

Comment: As state updates are asynchronous calls, they will not get immediately update. Yes, you can use useEffect to get the correct value

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One last question , how can i use useEffect to save uploadUrl to localstorage as current url value ?

Comment: A much better way would be to move some of the state properties to CreateBook component. Update the fields related to CreateBook component in there and pass it to the parent component when Submit event is triggered. Update the list with the current book. Link to codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/embed/wonderful-chandrasekhar-myv6x?file=/src/LocalStorage.js

Comment: ty for the answer and for the codesandbox ! sorry i cant give you vote because i m new and have no reputation.